# Keras.utils fails to Import

Tags: python-3.x, keras

Below image shows part of the code to train a simple deep CNN(Convolutional Neural Network), on CIFAR small images data set.
I have imported,  import keras.utils ( Highlighted in red)

[image]

However, I still get the below error:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can import `to_categorical` in keras like shown below.

```
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
```

It can be used like shown below.

```
Y = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1]

Y = to_categorical(Y)

print(Y)

# output
array([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try importing `np_utils` from `keras.utils` and use like this

```
from keras.utils import np_utils
np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
```

Answer (score -1):

You're following a wrong practice of importing python modules. You should go for either of the following practices:

> from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
>
> y_train = to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
>   y_test = to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

```
                   OR
```

> from keras.utils import np_utils
>
> y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
>   y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

You can call only the module/function that you've imported. Say, if you use,
*from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical*
                                                                                      that means you're importing **to_categorical** function from **keras.utils.np_utils** package. So, you can only call **to_categorical** function. But you're trying to call **keras.utils.to_categorical**, which is not imported. Also, you can't directly import 
**to_categorical** from **utils** without importing **np_utils** first.

**Rule of thumb:** If you type **from X import Y**, that means you've to call Y() as it is and not X.Y(). Doing that is redundant as well as wrong.

**Tip:** You don't need to mention **num_classes** as a parameter in **to_categorical**. Python interpreter will intelligently do that for you.